# Ranking topics in K-Means

Tags: clustering

I understand that clustering is meant to group items together, is there any ways that we can quantify saying Cluster A is more important than Cluster B? Other than counting the number of items in a cluster?

Comment: What do you mean by "important"? What are you trying to do? You may find my blog post [How to ask a statistics question?](http://www.statisticalanalysisconsulting.com/how-to-ask-a-statistics-question/) helpful.

Comment: For example, if we have 100 items, and we perform K-means (k=10), How can we rank the clusters according to their importance? Or is it I am missing how to quantify important ?

Comment: Again, what do you mean by "important"? I don't think it's likely a meaningful concept for clusters.

Comment: As Peter Flom has insisted on, "important" is not devised by the clustering itself. The clusters being important or not depends drastically on what you did the clustering for in the first place. For example if you did some sort of clustering for market segmentation, an important cluster could be a one that "appreciates" your brand but is not "saturated" yet by that specific market. Think about what you want and edit your question please.

Comment: I am clustering documents, and the features in the documents are represented using TF-IDF. My idea is important topics are the topics with centroid vector contains many terms wight high tf-idf score, and not sure if that's a vague claim.